# Vista Fails to Boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, boot

I just installed Windows 7, and I am running it in triple boot (Ubuntu/7/Vista). W7 boots just fine, and Ubuntu is fine, but when I try to boot vista all I see is a black screen, and then the computer resets. Does anybody know why this is happening/how to fix it?

Edit: My pimary bootloader is grub, however when I boot to windows it refuses to boot to either copy of windows directly. In grub, If I select Windows 7 it goes to the Windows bootloader, and if I select Windows Vista it gives me an error about no bootmgr(Boot Manager?) being present.

Comment: What bootloader are you using? Grub?

Comment: Also, W7 was installed on a separate partition?

Comment: Yes. One physical drive, Vista and 7 are on separate partitions.

Comment: Posting your grub menu.lst, your partition layout, and the OS install order would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try repairing/recreating the boot sector with [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).  It is basically an advanced boot editor with support for multiple operating systems including Vista, 7 and Linux.  Runs from within Windows.

> With EasyBCD, almost anything is
>   possible. Setting up and configuring
>   Windows boot entries is simple, and
>   there is no easier way to quickly boot
>   right into Linux, Mac OS X, or BSD
>   straight from the Windows Vista
>   bootloader - on the fly, no expert
>   knowledge needed!
>
> EasyBCD is used and recommended by
>   Microsoft, PC-World, PC-Magazine,
>   Softpedia, PC-Welt, and dozens more!
>   In the words of Harry McCracken (VP &
>   Editor-in-Chief of PC World):
>   "[EasyBCD] impressed the editors with
>   its functionality and usability. These
>   are some of the most well-crafted
>   services available - congratulations
>   to EasyBCD!" Don't get left out –
>   download it today, it's free!!

Comment: That program worked. Turns out somewhere along the way the bootloader had lost what drive Vista was on, and I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Which order did you install the oses in, if you installed 7 after vista you should be able to access vista from the 7 bootloader so you'd go grub 7 bootloader then choose vista from the list.

I would expect that 7 would replace the vista bootloader with it's own and add the vista partition to it's list.

Comment: If you read the question you'd note that finding Vista's entry is not my problem. It appears exactly as you said, and Vista is in 7's bootloader. The problem is that Vista doesn't boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Grub to [hide](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/DOS-Windows.html) the Vista partition when booting Windows 7 and vice versa, so that neither Microsoft OS can interfere with the other. If you hide the Windows 7 partition before installing Vista (assuming you install Windows 7 first), then Vista will put its boot loader on its own partition instead of on Windows 7's partition.